# How to display a profile picture from Firebase login data -in web?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the code

```
document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                displayName: displayName,
                email: email,
                emailVerified: emailVerified,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                uid: uid,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                providerData: providerData
              }, null, '  ');
            });
```

How to display it as a profile picure in

```
<img src="url from above data"></img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you login, (listen to onAuthStateChanged observer) get the photoURL via firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL. You can embed the photoURL dynamically:
`document.getElementById('photoURL').innerHTML ='<img src="'+firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL+'"/>';`

Comment: Not working .I tried to use ` document.getElementById('PhotoURL').src =photoURL;` . But the src of image is rendering as null.Help!

Comment: It could be that the current user does not have a photoURL. What type of provider are you using to sign in the user?